# How to create Liquibase changeset for below Postgres index creation statement - "using btree"

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-sql

```
create index if not exists department_index 
   on department using btree (department_id);
```

How can I create a Liquibase changeset for the above Postgresql? I have to use "using btree" feature in order to attain the desired performance,

Comment: There is nothing special about this index. `btree` is the default if nothing else is specified. Just use `<createIndex>`

Answer (score 0):

The default index is `btree` if you don't specify something else. You can use the `createIndex` entity to do this.

Reference:
[Liquibase Documentation: createIndex](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-index.html)